# problems with accessing webcam output in c# application

Tags: c#, windows, computer-vision, webcam

i know this is most likely a duplication and i am truly sorry for that but most of the solutions i found was either +7 years outdated, bugged or consume so much memory

all i need is an efficient way to access the webcam to record and display to use it in a computer vision project to detect moving objects and such, with an HD output (using HD camera of course)

also if there is a library that would help with the computer vision that would also be great

any information, tips or experience would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance and have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [AForge.net](http://www.aforgenet.com/), it's available as a nuget package and gets the job done.

Here is [an example](http://en.code-bude.net/2013/01/02/how-to-easily-record-from-a-webcam-in-c/) of it. It's a winform application, but I use this library in WPF app as well.

[EDIT] Actually, I think I found what you're looking for, download [this](https://azureinfo.microsoft.com/rs/microsoftdemandcenter/images/Kit-DetecteurMouvements-sur-Azure.zip). It's a piece of code that has been written for a french azure contest. It's a motion detector written with aforge.net. There is 2 part to it, the first is a wpf client that capture movement. The second is an azure website where the image captured is uploaded automatically.